# How to loop a BSTR?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a BSTR that contains a lots of charechter.

```
        BSTR theFile = NULL;
        int res = comSmartspeak -> readTheFile(fileName, &theFile);
```

I want to read the first line and i don't know how to do it.

this is the pseudoCode that i came up with:

```
        string firstLine = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < SysStringLen(theFile) ; i++)
        {
            if (theFile[i] == '\n')
            {
                break;
            }else
            {
                firstLine += theFile[i] ;
            }
        }
```

*Im new to VC++.*

Comment: You already now how to read one line from a text file, so return an array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
//another option

BSTR comStr = ::SysAllocString(L"First line of text\nSecond line of text\nThird line of text\nFourth line of text...");

    std::wstring ws(comStr, SysStringLen(comStr));

    std::wstring::size_type pos = ws.find_first_of('\n');
    if (pos != std::wstring::npos)
    {
        std::wcout << ws.substr(0, pos);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this assuming you are free to use std::wstring so that you don't have to calculate the length of the first line beforehand:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    BSTR a_bstr = ::SysAllocString(L"First line of text\nSecond line of text\nThird line of text\nFourth line of text...");
    std::wstring wide_str;
    unsigned int len = ::SysStringLen(a_bstr);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if (a_bstr[i] != '\n')
            wide_str += a_bstr[i];
        else
            break;
    }

    // wide_str holds your first line
    std::wcout << "First line: " << wide_str << std::endl;
    ::SysFreeString(a_bstr);
    return 0;
}
```